# C weird function variable assignment

Tags: c, function, hex

I found this code while I was learning how to make a Virtual Machine. But I haven't got a clue what this function does. Do any of you know what this function is doing?

```
void decode( int instr )
{
instrNum = (instr & 0xF000) >> 12;
reg1     = (instr & 0xF00 ) >>  8;
reg2     = (instr & 0xF0  ) >>  4;
reg3     = (instr & 0xF   );
imm      = (instr & 0xFF  );
}
```

The variable `instr` = 1.

Comment: Before learning how to make a Virtual Machine, learn the C language ant is't operators. Google and wikipedia may help.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys! I couldn't have asked for better responses!

Comment: What do you mean with your last sentence?

Comment: All the answers you guys gave where great! I actually understand whats's going on now.

Comment: Sorry about this but can I ask one more question? When creating a Virtual Machine do you have to encode the instructions into 1's and 0's or is there anything wrong with interpreting the instruction directly using some form of custom assembly code?

Comment: @user3318845 Hi there & welcome to Stack Overflow. If you found an answer helpful, you can show your appreciation to the poster by giving it an "upvote", click the up arrow next to the answer. Also you should accept the best answer as the correct one, by clicking the "check mark" next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is saving specific sets of 4 bits (called [nibbles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)) from the variable `instr` into other variables `instrNum`, `reg1`, etc (these other variables must have a global scope as they're not defined here).

Consider for example if `instr` was `0x1234`

```
instrNum = (0x1234 & 0xF000) >> 12; 
         = (0x1000) >> 12;
         = 1      
reg1 = (0x1234 & 0xF00) >> 8;
     = (0x0200) >> 8;
     = 2
reg2 = (0x1234 & 0xF0) >> 4;
     = (0x0030) >> 4;
     = 3
reg3 = (0x1234 & 0xF);
     = (0x0004);
     = 4
imm = (0x1234 & 0xFF);
     = (0x0034);
     = 52
```

So it's taking each nibble of the variable `instr` and saving it into a separate variable. The last variable `imm` gets the last byte. `&` and `>>` are bit operators, [`AND` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_AND_.22.26.22) for seperating out bits and the [right shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Right_shift_.3E.3E). 

*Why* it's saving these is anyone's guess, we would need to know what type those variables are and what they're used for, but that's *what* is happening anyway

Comment: Definitely not "every byte", you meant "nibble" since these are 4-bit fields.

Answer (score 1):

Those are [bit operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C), which are often used to compactly store some flags within a single integer. This function "reads" bits from the argument `instr` and writes the results to other fields.

Answer (score 1):

This function seems to decode an instruction `instr` into a 4-bit instruction code (`instNum`), and up to three registers 4-bit codes (`reg1` to `reg3`). In your virtual machine, there seems also an encoding for immediate 8 bit operands (`imm`). Here an illustration of my guess of the 16-bit instruction set of the VM:

[image]